# How to go over every item in an order list using jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

When the page in load/reloaded, I need to loop over each each list item in the order list and apply some logic to it.

Here is what I have done but nothing is being printed in the console as expected.

```
$(function() {

    $(window).load(function(){
        //$( "#selected_sortable_control_570_0 li").each(function(index)
        //$( "#selected_sortable_control_570_0 > li").each(function(index)
        $( "ul.selected_sortable_control_570_0 > li").each(function(index)
        {
            console.log( $( this ).attr('id') );

        });

    });

});
```

Here is my HTML markup

```
<ul id="selected_sortable_control_570_0">
    <li id="test1">Test 1</li>
    <li id="test2">Test 2</li>
    <li id="test3">Test 3</li>
</ul>
```

How can I correctly loop over each item?

Comment: Either of your commented lines should work.  There must be a different issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

UL has id -> `id="selected_sortable_control_570_0"`

Use `ul#selected_sortable_control_570_0 > li` as selector in $ function.

Working snippet

```js
$(function() {
  //$( "#selected_sortable_control_570_0 li").each(function(index)
  //$( "#selected_sortable_control_570_0 > li").each(function(index)
  $("ul#selected_sortable_control_570_0 > li").each(function(index) {
    console.log($(this).attr('id'));
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul id="selected_sortable_control_570_0">
  <li id="test1">Test 1</li>
  <li id="test2">Test 2</li>
  <li id="test3">Test 3</li>
</ul>
```

**Note:** Window load is not needed. Run the snippet it works.

Answer (score 0):

`selected_sortable_control_570_0` is an id in HTML but in your jQuery you are using a class selector. Change `.selected_sortable_control_570_0` to `#selected_sortable_control_570_0`.

Comment: look at the first 2 commented lines. I tried that but it did not work

Comment: This should work fine. Are you trying to execute this code in some online tool like jsFiddle? Please note that you don't have to wrap the code in document ready or window load in that case.

Answer (score 0):

```
                  $( "li").each(function(index,value)
                  {
                      console.log(value.id);

                  });
```

COdepen URL for reference- http://codepen.io/nagasai/pen/rLxzJE

added value and value.id will give id of each li and you can logic using each id